# Import "ruamel.yaml" could not be resolved

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

I am just a beginner in python.

I have a requirement of converting a JSON Object into a YAML file and trying to import `ruamel.yaml`.

I did install the command `pip3 install ruamel.yaml` and my python list package shows that it's available.

```
site-packages % pip3 list
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
certifi            2021.10.8
charset-normalizer 2.0.11
idna               3.3
pip                22.0.3
pytz               2021.3
PyYAML             6.0
requests           2.27.1
ruamel.yaml        0.17.21
ruamel.yaml.clib   0.2.6
setuptools         60.9.3
urllib3            1.26.8
```

Whereas when I am trying to import and use it in the python script it is giving me below error.

`Import "ruamel.yaml" could not be resolved`

Could someone please suggest how to resolve this.?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! are you using `Import` with `I` uppercase? import must be in lower case

Answer (score 0):

When Python cannot find a module you get an error looking like:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ruamel.yaml
```

This might be because you are using some non-standard installation/execution environment, or because you try to run this from an editor. Some of those don't understand the concept of namespaces in Python.

It could also be that `pip3` is not installing for the `python` that you are using to run the program. That is easy to check by installing some other package using `pip3` and trying to import that.

In either case make sure you test your program running with the python that corresponds to `pip3` ( using `type pip3` or `which pip3` resp `type python` ), or install using:

```
 python -m pip install ruamel.yaml
```

and then run the program with `python your_prog.py`

Comment: `python -c 'import sys; sys.stdout = None; import this; print(*[this.d.get(c,c) for c in this.s.splitlines()[-1]], sep="", file=sys.stderr)'`